# Enviar texto de textarea para div

Tags: javascript

Boas comunidade, tenho o seguinte script que pega o texto da textarea e a coloca dentro de uma div após o ENTER.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('textarea').keypress(
function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
        if(msg!='')

        $('<div class="msg_b">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
        $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
    }
});
```

Se a div "msg_b" estiver escrita em HTML direto no body o script funciona, mas neste caso especifico eu preciso que a div "msg_b" seja um elemento js e desta forma não consigo fazer com que o ENTER envie o texto introduzido na textarea para a div.

```
  var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ username +'</div>';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
            element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"><div class="msg_body"><div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div><div class="msg_b">This is from B</div><div class="msg_push"></div></div></div><div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div></div>';








            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;
```

Se essas div's sairem de dentro desse elemento e ficarem no próprio HTML A mensagem de texto da textarea já vai para dentro da div "msg_b".

```
<div class="msg_box" style="right:290px">
<div class="msg_head">User
<div class="close">x</div>
</div>
<div class="msg_wrap">
    <div class="msg_body">
        <div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div>
        <div class="msg_b">This is from B, and its amazingly kool nah... i know it even i liked it :)</div>

        <div class="msg_push"></div>
    </div>
<div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: O que tem essa variável `element`? é um elemento ou uma string de HTML?

Comment: @Sergio é um elemento de HTML. O Texto deveria aparecer dentro da <div class="msg_b"></div>

Comment: Continuo sem ter a certeza se `element` é um objeto ou uma string. Podes juntar mais código na pergunta para a clarificar?

Comment: @Sergio será que deu para perceber? eu não sou muito bom em desenvolver código javascript, ainda, mas neste caso eu preciso que o conjunto de divs passem pelo javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve o seu problema:

```js
var username = "João"; //exemplo
var id = "_qrt4"; //exemplo
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ username +'</div>';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
            element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"><div class="msg_body"><div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div><div class="msg_b">This is from B</div><div class="msg_push"></div></div></div><div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div></div>'

$('body').append(element) //Adiciona o elemento como um child

$('textarea').keypress(
function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        if(msg!=''){// Como mais de uma linha no if, os colchetes são necessários
            $('<div class="msg_b">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
            $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        $(this).val(''); //O esvaziamento deve ocorrer ao final de tudo
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Aqui o método [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Basicamente funciona assim:

```
 elementoPai.append('aqui virá um novo filho ao elemento pai');
```

**Ele poderia ser escrito da mesma maneira que o seu exemplo:**

```js
var username = "João";
var id = "_qrt4";
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ username +'</div>';
            element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
            element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"><div class="msg_body"><div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div><div class="msg_b">This is from B</div><div class="msg_push"></div></div></div><div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div></div>';

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;  


$('textarea').keypress(
function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        if(msg!=''){
        $('<div class="msg_b">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
        $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        
    $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Foi apenas uma quetão de preferências, já que o `append` é mais prática. A questão essencial está no fato de:

- A variáveis `userName` e `Id` devem ser declaradas.
- É o script com o `keypress()` deve vir após a criação das tags, para que ele as reconheça.

Comment: Resolveu! wow :) pode me explicar q diferença fez esse append? muito obrigado !

Comment: Claro, irei editar a resposta.

Comment: Pronto @DavidConcha, fiz a edição, dê uma olhada.